# Line integral work done by the force F

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem that I just don't get.

I am supposed to evaluate the line integral for the work done by the two-dimensional force **F** = (y, 2x) going from the origin O to the point P = (1,1). The path goes from O to Q = (1,0) along the x-axis, and from Q straight up to P = (1,1) along the y-axis. The textbook define the integrals as follow (this is an example in the book):

$\int_{0}^{1} F_x(x,0)$ $dx$ + $\int_{0}^{1} F_y(1,y)$ $dy$

= 0 + 2 $\int_{0}^{1} dy$ = 2

I understand how they get $F_x(x,0)$ and $F_y(1,y)$ (I think). What I don't understand is how this becomes 0 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation can be very confusing. Your force is given by the function: $F(x,y) = \langle y, 2x \rangle$.

Therefore, the components of the force are given by the functions:

$F_x(x,y)= y$, and $F_y(x,y)= 2x$

On the first path, $x$ is varying but y is constantly 0, so:

$F_x(x,y)= F_x(x,0)= 0$

On the second path, $y$ is varying but x is constantly 1, so:

$F_y(x,y)= F_y(1,y)= 2(1)=2$

Answer (score 1):

When u r going from 0,0 to 1,0 the coordinate y is constant and hence become f(0,2x) and u r displacing the mass in x direction so u want the force in x direction only which is 0 so integration becomes.
Same way in 1,0 to 1,1 x is constant and we want force in y direction to find work which is constant equal to 2.

Comment: To rephrase: $F_x$ is the $x$-component of the force, which on the first path is 0, because your equation defining $F$ has $F_x = y$ (the $x$-component of the force is the y coordinate of the position). On the second path, $F_y=2$, because the $y$-component of the force is given by $F_y=2x$, which on the second path is 2.